# Please I need help understanding this SYNONYM & GRANT exercise

Tags: oracle

Why isn't the answer "SELECT* FROM GARAGE.CARS;"?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You cannot query the GARAGE because it is a server role. Role can contain a set of permissions etc and do not direct you to data. It might allow you to query some data but you never use a role name inside the query. The same is for FRED - it is a login so you don't use login in query.

Comment: Amazing. That makes sense. Thank you Sir

Comment: @JayJason  This answer is wrong. JOHN is a "login", too, or more precisely a user name and therefore a schema name. So why is `select * from JOHN.CARS;`correct if a "login" can't be used in queries?